# In email Template set the receiver approval person name

Tags: email-template, approval-process

I have created Approval process and they have 2 steps if salary is > 20000$ and < 40000$ email sent to first manager and if salary > 40000$ then first manager ask to second manager who is senior how we can set that name in To part.

in To part reciever name how we can pick
Example

```
    Assigned To
    To {!USer. ?????}

    user expected salary is 30000$ please Approve or reject.

    Thanks
    {!User.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the merge field you are looking for is:

```
{!Receiving_User.Name}
```

Comment: only after to no name getting
To 
    user expected salary is 30000$ please Approve or reject.

    Thanks
    Jhon